Azure Logic App - trigger several Sharepoint List using 'When an item is created or modified'
I am trying to find a good approach to check for changes in particular sharepoint lists.
I want to use Logic App to:

1: create a Recurrence trigger
2: Get Sharepoint Lists
3: filter the lists
4: pass filtered list (of lists) to 'For Each' activity
5: check sharepoint lists in terms of new/updated items using a trigger 'When item is created or modified'

Not sure though, if the 5th step would work, as the trigger should trigger once a new item appears or is updated. So, in the above example, the sharepoint trigger ('When item is created or modified') would run for eternity?
Right now I want to focus on Logic App, it should retrieve a list that has been modified (item added or updated) and pass the name of the list to ADF.
Do you perhaps have a better solution using Logic App?

The use of a trigger is the first step, hence “trigger”, it sets off the flow.

Your configuration will work but sometimes it will go on indefinite running mode if When item is created or modified triggers doesn't get any new or modified item in the specified list. As a result, it will create multiple runs when the recurrence triggers condition is satisfied but when it reaches to When item is created or modified triggers, it might go on a long running mode if no new item is added or modified.
So as suggested by @Skin , you need to add the triggers in the first step.
In order to add multiple triggers in the first step, you need to add your codes in code view as illustrated in this Q&A but post that you need to continue with your further development in code view only as designer will not work afterwards.
References-
Limits and configuration reference guide - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Learn.
